# Display feeds from twitter in my wordpress account

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

I have rss feeds from my twitter account at url-> https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyp8Wwo8-dxWdPjO0atNZJbKPpy0LRaDTszisMWZhsdXU0XYOs/exec

I am using the following code to display the feeds but no able to do so. Result is no item.

```
<?php // Get RSS Feed(s)
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php' );

// Get a SimplePie feed object from the specified feed source.
$rss = fetch_feed( 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyp8Wwo8-dxWdPjO0atNZJbKPpy0LRaDTszisMWZhsdXU0XYOs/exec' );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : // Checks that the object is created correctly

    // Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to 5. 
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity( 5 ); 

    // Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems );

endif;
?>

<ul>
    <?php if ( $maxitems == 0 ) : ?>
        <li><?php _e( 'No items', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink. ?>
        <?php foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>"
                    title="<?php printf( __( 'Posted %s', 'my-text-domain' ), $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a') ); ?>">
                    <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there not a plugin for WordPress that can do this? If not you will need to look into using the Twitter API and integrating that into the footer

Comment: thanks for reply ... i was trying to do it without the plugin. just giving it a try , if not  successful , will have to use the plugin only

Answer (score 0):

There is a twitter plugin that will do the work for you. To visit the plugin site, [Click Here](http://aarondcampbell.com/wordpress-plugin/twitter-widget-pro/)

Or you can search the wp plugin repo for `twitter-widget-pro`.

It gives you a widget that properly handles twitter feeds, including parsing @username, #hashtag, and URLs into links. It supports displaying profiles images, and even lets you control whether to display the time and date of a tweet or how log ago it happened (about 5 hours ago, etc).

Answer (score 0):

if you are aware with the usage of wordpress plugins, i recommend this one:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/latest-tweets-widget/

the installed plugin is self-describing.